# How do you optimally structure a MongoDB database to fetch all properties of a user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an app where a user object has multiple game objects. What would be the proper strategy for fetching all of a user's games from a mongoDB database?

As far as I can tell I have 2 options:

1. Give users a game property that is an array of ids of games that the user has and then fetch each game individually

e.g. 
example user

```
{
  _id: '1342',
  name: 'Dave',
  games: [
    '12345678',
    'fgnhe45rnd',
  ],
}
```

example game

```
{
  _id: '12345678',
  name: 'Fluxx',
}
```

2. The opposite. Give each game a users property that is an array of ids of users that own that game. Then fetch all games that have a specific user's id.

e.g. 
example user

```
{
  _id: '1342',
  name: 'Dave',
}
```

example game

```
{
  _id: '12345678',
  name: 'Fluxx',
  users: [
    '1342',
    '5783',
  ],
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Case

1. A user object has multiple game objects
2. To fetching all of a user's games

> I will suggest you use the **first option**.

Example user

```
{
  _id: '1342',
  name: 'Dave',
  games: [
    '12345678',
    'fgnhe45rnd',
  ],
}
```

Example game

```
{
  _id: '12345678',
  name: 'Fluxx',
}
```

### Reason

As you mentioned in the use case, you are fetching all of a user's games.

#### First Option

So if you are fetching all of Dave's game, you only need to get Dave's list of games then refer each game to its data. This is **1+n fetch** where **n is number of game Dave has**.

#### Second Option

If you use the second option, you will need to go through every single game to check if users list in the game contains Dave. And then you have to record the data only if Dave is in the list. This is **N fetch** where **N is total number of games in the database**.

In general, N is larger than n+1.

Answer (score 0):

If you need user's games,you should use 1.For example i need kevin's games: you can get kevin's games with 2.?